# How to create linked service from azure analysis service to azure synapse SQL pool

Tags: azure-synapse

How to pull data from cube that is hosted on Azure analysis service and load data in SQL pools of synapse

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use Azure Data Factory for data movement.
There's no built-in connector for Azure Analysis Service in Data Factory. But since Azure Analysis Services uses Azure Blob Storage to persist storage, you can use the connector for Azure Blob Storage.

In Data Factory, use a Copy Activity with Blob Storage as source and Azure Synapse Analytics as sink.

More on Azure Data Factory here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/

Available connectors in Data Factory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview